# Google spreadsheet Search using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to build a search option where user will input their ID and they will see the result of that corresponding ID which is stored in google spreadsheet.

Like user will input:
1 and they will see result : Nitu
5 and they will see result : Dipon
 [image]

```html
<input id="id" type="text" placeholder="Your ID">
<input id="search" type="submit" value="Search">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function displayContent(json) {
   var string = "<table>";      
            var len = json.feed.entry.length;
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                  var id = json.feed.entry[i].gsx$id.$t;
                  var name = json.feed.entry[i].gsx$name.$t;
      string += '<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + name + '</td></tr>';
            }
   string += "</table>";
   $(string).appendTo('body');
        }   
  </script>
<script src="http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1WMvFqepPmQUVwTFFUZW_3SfSt1ZBr_AEy_XdUXZ72ng/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=displayContent" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can fetch data from my google sheet using the above code snippet. But I don't want to fetch all data at a time. I want only specific data based on search with ID.

So now how can I integrate this search feature in javascript?

Comment: So you only want the name of the user?

Comment: I want the functionality like the following way: 
user will input: 1 and they will see result : Nitu
if they input 5 and they will see result : Dipon. 
And yes I want name of the specific ID.
See the image please.

Comment: Remove <td>' + id + '</td> is this what your after?

Comment: No.

**I can fetch data from my google sheet using the above code snippet. I got it from google. But I don't want to fetch all data at a time. I want only specific data based on search with ID.**

Please read my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Structured Query](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#send_a_structured_query_for_rows) for google spreadsheet API.

So if make a `GET` request with proper Structured Query and you will get the relevant data only. in your case add `sq=id==5` as query parameter.

So rather then get the whole data onload and parse it afterwads, you should make a function which will make proper `GET` request and fetch you Only the data you  need.

```
var fetchName = function(ID, workSheetID){
    var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/'+workSheetID+'/od6/public/values?sq=id='+ID+'&alt=json-in-script&callback=?';

    $.get( url, function( data ) {
          //Parse and Do Your Stuff Here
    });
}
```

[Plunker Sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/6fSSbLLH9dTcoZSRCKuv?p=preview)

Hope this helps. Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing a for loop just use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the corresponding ID. For exmaple:

```
 function displayContent(json) {
    var output = json.feed.entry.filter(function(name){
      return name.gsx$id.$t === '2'

    })
            $('body').append(" <p>" + output[0].gsx$name.$t + "</p>");
```

Heres the edited version, just replace '2' with your id or with the input value getter and it should work. Notice you need to reference the output in array like syntax. [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/dukidi/edit?html,output)

Comment: It's not working :(
`var name =  json.feed.entry.filter(function(element){
   return element.gsx$id.$t === 2
})

var test = name.gsx$name.$t; 

`
It shows an error **Cannot read property '$t' of undefineddisplayContent**

Comment: sounds like theres something with the google spreadsheet api that you have to play with. I'm not sure of the syntax, you will have to play around with it and debug it but that should be the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Cross reference your code with the answer provided carefully!

1) your filter:       --> return element.gsx$id.$t === 2
   The comparison may not return the expected result
                      --> return name.gsx$id.$t === '2'

2) The returned data if your comparison produces any result would be in the variable 'name'. ***var name*** is in an array. You are to use indexes to access the array elements. Therefore, taking that into account, you should change yout code to:
    **var test = name[0].gsx$id.$t;**
    Here you are correctly accessing the data returned.

3) Always make sure there is data to access. **Your array must not be empty** if you try to access  it.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [POST Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you